# Iterate over nested dictionary

Tags: python

Is there an easy way of iterating over nested dictionary, which may consist of other objects like lists, tuples, then again dictionaries so that iteration covers all the elements of these other objects?

For example, if I type a key of a nested dictionary object, I would get it all listed in the Python interpreter.

---

**[edit]** here is example dictionary:

```
{
'key_1': 'value_1',
'key_2': {'key_21': [(2100, 2101), (2110, 2111)],
      'key_22': ['l1', 'l2'],
      'key_23': {'key_231': 'v'},
      'key_24': {'key_241': 502,
             'key_242': [(5, 0), (7, 0)],
             'key_243': {'key_2431': [0, 0],
                 'key_2432': 504,
                 'key_2433': [(11451, 0), (11452, 0)]
                },
             'key_244': {'key_2441': {'key_24411': {'key_244111': 'v_24411',
                                'key_244112': [(5549, 0)]
                               },
                          'key_24412':'v_24412'
                         },
                 'key_2441': ['ll1', 'll2']
                }
            },
     }
}
```

sorry for being unreadable, but I did the best that I could.

Comment: For the second part of your question, you might want [a pretty printer](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/pprint/).

Comment: Why down-voting without providing reason for it? Is question badly asked? Is dictionary object example bad? It's just part of much larger dictionary for which I want to use graphviz in automated manner if possible without crawling by hand

Comment: well, some people are just trigger happy when they see other people attempting to iterate through dictionaries or hash tables

Comment: Why isn't there an accepted answer? Graddy's and @NeilenMarais solutions work well.

Comment: @zelusp: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577982-recursively-walk-python-objects/

Comment: @theta how'd you get that code to give you a tuple of keys and a list of values instead of a list of keys and each value separately?

Answer (score 19):

```
def recurse(d):
  if type(d)==type({}):
    for k in d:
      recurse(d[k])
  else:
    print d
```

Comment: @theta: works fine, for one interpretation of your question. If you want it to loop through lists as well, add an `elif isinstance([], (list, tuple)):` and then `for v in d: recurse(v)`.

Comment: NOTE : Recurssive approach fails in case of large nested dicts... Gives error : maximum recursion depth exceeded. So it depends upon your requirement. Use iterative one in case of large nested dicts problems.

Answer (score 7):

A generator version of Graddy's `recurse()` answer above that should not explode on strings, and also gives you the compound key (cookie crumb trail?) showing how you arrived at a certain value:

```
def recurse(d, keys=()):
    if type(d) == dict:
         for k in d:
            for rv in recurse(d[k], keys + (k, )):
                yield rv
    else:
        yield (keys, d)

for compound_key, val in recurse(eg_dict):
    print '{}: {}'.format(compound_key, val)
```

produces output (using the example dictionary provided in the question):

```
('key_1',): value_1
('key_2', 'key_21'): [(2100, 2101), (2110, 2111)]
('key_2', 'key_22'): ['l1', 'l2']
('key_2', 'key_23', 'key_231'): v
('key_2', 'key_24', 'key_241'): 502
('key_2', 'key_24', 'key_243', 'key_2433'): [(11451, 0), (11452, 0)]
('key_2', 'key_24', 'key_243', 'key_2432'): 504
('key_2', 'key_24', 'key_243', 'key_2431'): [0, 0]
('key_2', 'key_24', 'key_242'): [(5, 0), (7, 0)]
('key_2', 'key_24', 'key_244', 'key_2441'): ['ll1', 'll2']
```

In Python 3 the second yield loop should be replaceable with `yield from`. This generator could be made more general by replacing the `type(d) == dict` test with `isinstance(d, collections.Mapping)`, using the Mapping ABC from the collections module.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

d = {'key_1': 'value_1',
     'key_2': {'key_21': [(2100, 2101), (2110, 2111)],
           'key_22': ['l1', 'l2'],
           'key_23': {'key_231': 'v'},
           'key_24': {'key_241': 502,
                      'key_242': [(5, 0), (7, 0)],
                      'key_243': {'key_2431': [0, 0],
                                  'key_2432': 504,
                                  'key_2433': [(11451, 0), (11452, 0)]},
                      'key_244': {'key_2441': ['ll1', 'll2']}}}}

def search_it(nested, target):
    found = []
    for key, value in nested.iteritems():
        if key == target:
            found.append(value)
        elif isinstance(value, dict):
            found.extend(search_it(value, target))
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            for item in value:
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    found.extend(search_it(item, target))
        else:
            if key == target:
                found.append(value)
    return found

keys = [ 'key_242', 'key_243', 'key_242', 'key_244', 'key_1' ]

for key in keys:
    f = search_it(d, key)
    print 'Key: %s, value: %s' % (key, f[0])
```

Output:

```
Key: key_242, value: [(5, 0), (7, 0)]
Key: key_243, value: {'key_2433': [(11451, 0), (11452, 0)], 'key_2432': 504, 'key_2431': 
 [0, 0]}
Key: key_242, value: [(5, 0), (7, 0)]
Key: key_244, value: {'key_2441': ['ll1', 'll2']}
Key: key_1, value: value_1
```

Answer (score 2):

Iterating over a nested dictionary containing unexpected nested elements.

Here is my solution :

```
# d is the nested dictionary

for item in d:
    if type(item) == list:
        print "Item is a list"
        for i in item: print i
    elif type(item) == dict:
        print "Item is a dict"
        for i in item: print i
    elif type(item) == tuple:
        print "Item is a tuple"
        for i in item: print i
    else:
        print "Item is not a list, neither a dict and not even a tuple"
        print item
```

I think the above example is very general, you can mold it for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a general-purpose wrapper generator, like the following:

```
def recursive(coll):
    """Return a generator for all atomic values in coll and its subcollections.
    An atomic value is one that's not iterable as determined by iter."""
    try:
        k = iter(coll)
        for x in k:
            for y in recursive(x):
                yield y
    except TypeError:
        yield coll


def test():
    t = [[1,2,3], 4, 5, [6, [7, 8], 9]]
    for x in recursive(t):
        print x
```

Comment: I get: `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`

Comment: Strings are iterable so this will blow up if you have any strings within the list/dictionary

Answer (score 0):

I took a small portion of your dictionary

```
d = {
    'key_1': 'value_1',
    'key_2': {'key_21': [(2100, 2101), (2110, 2111)]},
    'key_22': ['l1', 'l2'],
    'key_23': {'key_231': 'v'}
}
```

With a `NestedDict` it is straightforward to access all values.

```
>>> from ndicts.ndicts import NestedDict
>>> nd = NestedDict(d)
>>> list(nd.values())
['value_1', [(2100, 2101), (2110, 2111)], ['l1', 'l2'], 'v']
```

If you want to flatten this list you can use this recursive function

```
from typing import Iterable

def flatten(li):
    def wrap(x, result):
        if isinstance(x, Iterable) and type(x) is not str:
            for i in x:
                wrap(i, result)
        else:
            result.append(x)
    result = []
    wrap(li, result)
    return result
```

```
>>> flatten(list(nd.values()))
['value_1', 2100, 2101, 2110, 2111, 'l1', 'l2', 'v']
```