# Nested Dictionary Iteration in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary that has a few options key value pairs and then a sub_dict attribute that is a list of more dictionaries with the same attributes and these also have the potential to have sub_dicts all the way down.

In python I break it apart and work on them individually and change them one at a time and want to recombine the changed system with the whole one. I am not sure how to iterate through it though.

```
{base_system: {
name: "root",
description: "data dictionary",
common_data: {},
other_data: {},
more_data: {},
sub_systems: [
    {
        base_system: {
        name: "another system",
        description: "inherits from top level",
        sub_systems: [
            {
                base_system: {}
            },
            {
                base_system: {}
            }
        ]
        }
    },
    {
        base_system: {
            name: "one more system",
            description: "inheriting again",
            sub_systems: [
            {
                base_system: {
                name: "child system",
                description: "no kids here",
                other_data: {},
                more_data: {}
                }
            },
            {
                base_system: {
                name: "kid system",
                description: "no children here"
                }
            }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

}

I want to do something like this but I'm not sure what to do to make it recursive.

```
#Have some recursive function to dig through the overall dictionary then test:
if the_dict_object["space_system"]["name"] == changed_json_system["space_system"]["name"]:
  #then when it passes that if statement I can just set
  the_dict_object = changed_json_system
```

But I am not sure how to iterate through the nested dictionary and still have a hold of the overall object.

Comment: you want to compare all values?

Comment: I want to do a check for the name of the system/sub_system I just worked on to see if it matches the one I'm currently looking at in the dictionary and if it does I want to replace that subsystem with the one that I just worked on.

Comment: you may like this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335096/iterate-over-nested-dictionary/21528445#21528445

Answer (score 1):

You can use instanceof() method to check if something is a dict, then if true you can make your code to iterate through this dict. I would do a recursion in this case.

```
def read_dict(some_dictionary):
    for key, value in some_dictionary:

        if isinstance(value, dict): 
            # if value is another dict, iterate through the key,value pairs in value
            read_dict(value) 
        elif isinstance(value, list):
            # if value is a list, add your own code to iterate through a list
            pass
        else:
            #not a dict, do what you needed to do eg:
            print 'value of %s is %s' % (key, value) 

read_dict(the_dict_object)
```

Comment: instanceof?  Do you mean isinstance?

Comment: My mistake, yes isinstance :) Thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code that recursively walks through your dict structure.  For this example, it replaces the description with the upper-case of the description.

```
_DESC = "description"
_BASESYS = "base_system"
_SUBSYS = "sub_systems"

def uppercase_desc(system_info):
    """
    Change a system object such that the description is in upper-case.
    """
    if _BASESYS not in system_info:
        return

    subd = system_info[_BASESYS]
    if _DESC in subd:
        subd[_DESC] = subd[_DESC].upper()
    if _SUBSYS not in subd:
        return
    for d in subd[_SUBSYS]:
        uppercase_desc(d)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json
    with open("data.json", "rt") as f:
        s = f.read()
    system_info = json.loads(s)

    uppercase_desc(system_info)
    s = json.dumps(system_info, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    print(s)
```

The above code modifies the dictionary in-place.  It's a little trickier, but not bad, to make a copy as you go and return the copy.  This may be preferable.

The only tricky part here is that the code uses `copy.deepcopy()` by default.  Since we don't know what might be in the dictionary, and we want to return a copy, we can just call `copy.deepcopy()` on everything; it will trivially work and do the right thing on simple objects like `3` (integer object of value 3).

```
import copy

_DESC = "description"
_BASESYS = "base_system"
_SUBSYS = "sub_systems"

def uppercase_desc(system_info):
    """
    Change a system object such that the description is in upper-case.
    """
    if _BASESYS not in system_info:
        raise ValueError("only works on a system info dict")

    # put in the base_system key and an empty subdir
    newsubd = {}
    new_system_info = {_BASESYS: newsubd}

    subd = system_info[_BASESYS]
    for key, value in subd.items():
        if _DESC == key:
            newsubd[key] = value.upper()
        elif _SUBSYS == key:
            newsubd[key] = [uppercase_desc(d) for d in value]
        else:
            newsubd[key] = copy.deepcopy(value)
    return new_system_info

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import json
    with open("data.json", "rt") as f:
        s = f.read()
    system_info = json.loads(s)

    new_system_info = uppercase_desc(system_info)
    s = json.dumps(new_system_info, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    print(s)
```

P.S. The example data you posted isn't valid JSON.  I modified it by putting double-quotes around the keys, and pretty-printed it with nice indents, to make my test file `data.json`.  Here it is:

```
{
    "base_system": {
        "name": "root", 
        "description": "data dictionary", 
        "more_data": {}, 
        "common_data": {}, 
        "sub_systems": [
            {
                "base_system": {
                    "name": "another system", 
                    "sub_systems": [
                        {
                            "base_system": {}
                        }, 
                        {
                            "base_system": {}
                        }
                    ], 
                    "description": "inherits from top level"
                }
            }, 
            {
                "base_system": {
                    "name": "one more system", 
                    "sub_systems": [
                        {
                            "base_system": {
                                "more_data": {}, 
                                "other_data": {}, 
                                "name": "child system", 
                                "description": "no kids here"
                            }
                        }, 
                        {
                            "base_system": {
                                "name": "kid system", 
                                "description": "no children here"
                            }
                        }
                    ], 
                    "description": "inheriting again"
                }
            }
        ], 
        "other_data": {}
    }
}
```