# How do I approach moderate modification of a highly nested object with 100s of traces?

Tags: python, json, path, nested, transform

I have a bloated nested dictionary **A** I would like to transform into a concise, less nested dictionary **B** that hopes to become JSON. From a design perspective this can be done a couple of ways:

## The Switch Sifter

One way to do this is to walk **A** and pass it through a complicated series of switch statements that sifts the data into **B**'s shape. This is bad if **A** is relatively large since that would need many switch conditions or if one has many different bloated structures like **A** and need compose many different **switch sifters**. This is also bad if *traces* (any breadcrumb path to a deepest nested value) through **A** change in the future. "The only thing constant is change" though so this would be an issue with most approaches.

## The Map Transformer

I speculate that another way to do this is, while walking **A**, to use a lookup table that maps every possible trace from **A** onto every new trace that represents and builds **B**. Said differently, every value from every trace in **A** is mapped as the value of respective traces in **B**. Take a look at [this example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0zm1hsoe8a8gag1/JSONStructureComparison.pdf?dl=0). Making this requires the same knowledge of the **A** to **B** transformation logic needed to sift data in the **switch sifter** but makes that transformation highly readable as a lookup table. The downside to this approach is it's easy to break if **A**'s structure changes and the lookup table doesn't contain the new/changed trace case.

## The Map Sifter

I speculate that perhaps a better approach is a hybrid of the prior two that uses a lookup table to transform **A** into **B** for all known traces of **A** but then falls back on switching logic to handle new traces according to some rules known about the way **A** may change. Of course, all bets are off if the structure of **A** changes wildly.

## The Question

I tend to find examples of and have coded many a ***Switch Sifter*** to munge data structures. I've never made ***Map Transformers*** or ***Map Sifters*** and am wondering if they are effective in the situation where one is trying to simplify many highly nested, redundant structures each of which may have 200+ traces. I'm considering building a ***Map Sifter*** (or whatever that's called if it already has a name). Is there a better way of transforming JSON?

I'm working in Python (if you know of a library that could help me out). Below is starter code to play with the idea of a Map Transformer (if it be a viable approach)

```
import json

def recurse(d, keys=[]):
    # walk python object. Thanks to NeilenMarais @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335096/iterate-over-nested-dictionary
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            for rv in recurse(d[k], keys + [(k,type(d).__name__)]):
                yield rv
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i, v in enumerate(d):
            for rv in recurse(v, keys + [(i,type(d).__name__)]):
                yield rv
    else:
        yield (keys, d)
        
def pp_json(json_thing, sort=True, indents=4):
    # pretty print jsonesque object
    if type(json_thing) is str:
        print(json.dumps(json.loads(json_thing), sort_keys=sort, indent=indents))
    else:
        print(json.dumps(json_thing, sort_keys=sort, indent=indents))
    return None
    
aLongFluffyJson="""{
    "anAlrightKey1": "21.5",
    "key2": {
        "superfluousKey1":{
            "keyWhosNameIsTooLong1": "1",
            "keyWhosNameIsTooLong2": "2013-08-28",
            "anAlrightKey2": "435 PACIFIC AVENUE, 4TH FLOOR"
        }
    },
    "key3": [
        {
            "keyWhosNameIsTooLong3": "200045",
            "anAlrightKey3": "PeoplePlacesThings"
        },
        {
            "keyWhosNameIsTooLong3": "300045",
            "anAlrightKey3": "null"
        }
    ],
    "key4": {
        "key5": {
            "key6": "thisValueDoesntMatter",
            "key7": "iWishToBeAccessible"
        }
    }
}"""

aConciseJson="""{
        "anAlrightKey1": "21.5",
        "key2": {
                "keyNowShort1": "true",
                "keyNowShort2": "2013-08-28"
        },
        "key3": [
                {
                        "keyNowShort3": "200045",
                        "anAlrightKey3": "PeoplePlacesThings"
                },
                {
                        "keyNowShort4": "300045"
                }
        ],
        "key4": {
                "key5": {
                        "key6": "iWishToBeAccessible",
                        "key7": "iAlsoWishToBeAccessible",
                        "anAlrightKey2": "435 PACIFIC AVENUE, 4TH FLOOR"
                }
        }
}"""

aLongFluffyJson=json.loads(aLongFluffyJson)

aConciseJson=json.loads(aConciseJson)

pp_json(aConciseJson) #See what you're working with

# prepare what could be used to build the lookup table in a Map Transformer
for compound_key, val in recurse(aLongFluffyJson):
    print('{}: {}'.format(compound_key, val))    
print(" ")
for compound_key, val in recurse(aConciseJson): #this is missing the value type definition
    print('{}: {}'.format(compound_key, val))
```